# Android Studio 3.2.1 не работает Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Помогите пожалуйста. Установил Android Studio 3.2.1, подключил Firebase. При компиляции выдаёт ошибки:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1052: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1052: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\Home\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\17fcbff417648363465aee5fdd0ad3f9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сверь версии библиотек Firebase на их же сайте. Проверь так же правильно ли ты пихнул json файл в сам проект

Comment: Спасибо, версию поправил, действительно, автоматом прописівает не верно. Теперь: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.